# Use Activity or Fragment in Android Application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am new in android. I often use Activity to change from one screen to another screen with other function. Example from Home Page to Popular page. After that, i know about fragment but i never use it before. So, if i have a application with multi tab on a screen, not use TabHost here. Function of every tab very diffrent, ex : tab Home, tab Popular, tab News, tab Profile ... like Instagram App. I must use that

1. Activity to change Screen to another Screen, it means: i have Home Activity, Popular Activity, ... and change Activity when change Sreen. Each Activity have each layout.
2. Use fragment within one Activity. We have multi fragment, example HomeFragment, Popular Fragment... chang replace Fragment when change Screen.

What way is better ?
I want to ask when use only phone screen. ( small size screen, not for tablet).

Answer (score 4):

It's important to think of Android devices as more of a spectrum, than clear "phone" vs. "tablet" buckets. There are many instances where you might want to show more information on screen on `medium` and `large` screens. Sometimes, this translates to showing two "Activities" at once.

Using Fragments requires little overhead, but adds measurable flexibility, especially when considered early in the development process. If you use Fragments properly, adapting to larger screens is extremely simple. However, there are a few "gotchas" that may make Fragments appear to be more daunting that they actually are:

- `Fragment` classes must always be declared `public` (if it's a nested class, it must be `static`).
- In the parent `Activity` (or `FragmentActivity`), only add the root `Fragment` if `savedInstanceState == null`. If you are managing the state of your `Fragment` properly, everything is handled for you (scroll position, EditText values, etc).
- The parent `Activity` must call through to `onSavedInstanceState` in order for the `Fragment` to properly restore it's state.
- `setRetainInstance(true)` should only be used for "headless" Fragments. This is when you use a Fragment that has no UI, and isn't added to the back stack, which is typically used to do life-cycle dependent work.
- Fragments declared in XML cannot be used in a `FragmentTransaction` (and vice-versa).

Think of a `Fragment` as a modular view, that provides hooks (callbacks) to it's `Activity` when something important happens. The `Activity` decides, based on the available space, whether to launch a new `Activity`, or show a new `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either way. If you decide to use the Activity solution, create a base activity class that contains all the Tab functionality. You don't want to implement that in every Activity over and over again.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(...) {
        // Init tabs
    }

    // Methods for tab handling
}
```

Every Activity (Popular, Profile, Home, ...) extends BaseActivity

```
public class PopularActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
        super.onCreate(...);

        // Init only the popular activity elements here
    }
}
```

This way you implement the tab functionality only once and get it in every activity.

Comment: I only understand this way but i also think it like every screen have every activity, all of activity extends from BaseActivity. So, i don't know BaseActivity must init what . Please give some clue ... to more understand. Thanks you.