# Full-screen Fragment or Activity?

Tags: android

I'm building an android app where there is a button that will show a new screen. Should I use `Fragment` and `FrameLayout`, or create a new `Activity`?

I wanted to replicate the behaviour of the FaceBook app, where the user clicks a button, which then shows a new screen where the user will type what he/she wants to write

Comment: you can use activity for new screen.

Comment: I'd use Fragments everywhere I can, because they are more stable. Like in this here I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either **Activity** approach or **Fragment** approach. The decision should be based on what you want to do int the next screen. Over the years I find that using fragment is suitable for most of the scenarios. I prefer fragment because of its flexibility and re-usability(also no need to add activity tag in manifest one of my fav benifit lol).

Comment: +1 because I run into "NoActivityFoundException, are you sure you've specified the Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?" all the damn time. Even if you know you need to add it, I personally tend to forget about it.

Comment: @Zhuinden that is one of the most annoying exceptions that android throws. Wastes 30 seconds for 1 in every three new activity I create and forget to add to manifest.

Comment: @IllegalArgument Thanks, I'll try and use Fragments whenever possible then.

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are re-usable components. You can swap between fragments inside an Activity.

If you are going in to a new screen, best would be to use an Activity.

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in [Why using Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181751/why-using-fragments/24184364#24184364) previously, due to how Activities are destroyed and reconstructed on every single orientation change, I'd rather keep my things in Fragments for stability, and use Activities only where necessary.

So personally, I would recommend this setup for a start: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Comment: On configuration changes also fragments get recreated

Answer (score 1):

You havent really provided alot of information about what you would use it for. I would use an activity if it a competely new screen. Fragments, layouts and views etc are really things that an activity can have in them. If you wanted to just have a popup style view then you could use differnet views within the activity.

Comment: I wanted to replicate the behaviour of the FaceBook app, where the user clicks a button, which then shows a new screen where the user will type what he/she wants to write

Comment: Honestly for that I'd just use a DialogFragment.

Comment: if you are going to just display a kind of popup style entry box that will then copy the contense back to the orignal activity then use fragments, see @illegal Argument's comments above

Comment: @Zhuinden Thanks, I think DialogFragment is exactly what I need

Comment: I personally did http://stackoverflow.com/a/25056160/2413303 for a DialogFragment, it is also worth noting how to make it fill the parent if you'll need it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990726/how-to-make-dialogfragment-width-to-fill-parent