# Activities or fragments for 2d game

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

If i wanted to make a game that had a similar menu layout to games like candy crush would it be better to use fragments or activities.

So when the user clicks on the app icon your immediately hit with a loading screen (loading textures and media) then before actually getting to play a level you go through 2 or 3 different menus.

From past experience with activities it would be quite difficult to load all the game data in the first activity and keep a reference to it through 2 or more additional activities.

So is the answer here to use fragments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To Fragment or not to Fragment - Nested Fragments against Activities. Why should I use more than one Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927452/to-fragment-or-not-to-fragment-nested-fragments-against-activities-why-should)

Comment: Always use Fragments. You just answered your own question anyhow, so do what you know is right.